# Fancybox Oembed Anything

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, oembed

On the fancybox website they have an example of how to go about using 3rd party oembed to embed content from other websites inside of a fancybox.

They even have a great jsfiddle that can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PudLq/

Unfortunately, whenever I recreate this code on my computer, the fancybox does not embed itself and pop up nicely with the oembed content inside. Instead, I actually open the hyperlink and end up arriving at a embed formatted version of the site.

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2, and the newest version of fancybox2 from fancyapps.

Here is how I generally declared my links:

```
<a class="fancybox" 
href="https://soundcloud.com/white_lights"
rel="gallery1"
title = "WHITE LIGHTS">
    <div class="module" id="artist-1">
    my link
    </div>
</a>
```

My only script tags containing jquery contain solely the code from the jsFiddle.
My CSS has the declarations for #dummy and .fancybox-inner iframe at the very end of the cascade sheet.

What could I be doing wrong? Has anyone had any luck getting this to work? I'd love to see another running example on someone's live site.

edit: worth noting that normal fancyboxes which use image paths in the "href" field work just fine, as well as galleries etc.

Comment: Here is a working example of what you are looking for: http://duplexstudios.com/portfolio.html

Comment: are you testing in localhost or server?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast thank you! that's a big help!